# How can I chain RxJS promises when using the test scheduler?

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

In code that uses Observables with delayed delivery, I can use the TestScheduler to cause delivery to occur without an actual delay, in virtual time.  However, it seems that if I convert such Observables to Promises and attempt to chain them together, only the first Promise ever gets resolved. How can I test a system that uses delays like this without waiting for real time resolution to occur?

See the snipped below: note that changing 'sched' to 'async' and commenting out the 'flush' line causes it to behave as expected, except slowly. How can I get this chain of promises to run without the delays?

```js
var sched = new Rx.TestScheduler();
//var sched = Rx.Scheduler.async;

Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ().then (
  () => $("#test").text("100")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("200")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("300")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("400"));

sched.flush ();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.0/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after a Promise is resolved, its callbacks are not invoked until after flow of control returns back to the top level.  This means that after the first promise is resolved during the call to `sched.flush()` a new callback is queued, but this doesn't occur until after `sched.flush()` is finished.  But we still need `sched.flush()` to run again to make the second Observable complete, and so on.

In principle, this means that we just need to reinvoke `sched.flush()` a few times asynchronously in order to get all of the observables finished.  We can do this by creating a separate chain of Promises that flushes the scheduler on each callback. The only problem with this is that it's not clear how to tell whether or not the Observables are ready for it yet, as there's no clearly defined order of execution for unrelated Promise callbacks.

My solution is simply to create a Promise chain that executes a callback function that flushes the scheduler, then recursively reinserts itself until it finds that it no longer needs to do so.  This relies on the original callbacks producing some kind of side effect that can be tested (but as the requirement is for unit testing, this seems reasonable -- if there wasn't such an effect, it wouldn't be testable in the first case).  In real code, it would also need to perform any assertions, test teardown, etc, after detecting the end of the code.  I also arrange it so that it has a limited number of iterations so it doesn't recurse indefinitely if the tested code fails in some fashion.

```js
var sched = new Rx.TestScheduler();
var finished = false;
//var sched = Rx.Scheduler.async;

Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ().then (
  () => $("#test").text("100")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("200")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("300")).then (
  () => Rx.Observable.timer (100, sched).toPromise ()).then (
  () => $("#test").text("400")).then (
  () => finished = true );

let f = n => { 
   sched.flush (); 
   if (n > 0 && !finished) {
       return Promise.resolve(n - 1).then(f); 
   } 
   else {
       $("#test").append (" [" + n + " iterations left]");
   }
}
Promise.resolve(100).then(f);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.4.0/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```